# Protecting functions from empty DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, pandas, decorator-pattern

Pandas likes to throw cryptic errors when you feed its functions with empty `DataFrame`s saying nothing that would help you to identify the root cause. In order to avoid this I used to write conditions like this one all over the place:

```py
def normalize_null(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Replaces pd.NaT garbage with None."""

    if data.empty:
        return pd.DataFrame()

    return data.replace({pd.NaT: None})
```

I don't even remember if this particular operation fails on an empty `DataFrame`, but there are many that do so I just add it to every function just in case.

Then I thought why making it so ugly? Make it a decorator! So now I do this:

```py
@skip_if_empty(default=pd.DataFrame())
def normalize_null(data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Replaces pd.NaT garbage with None."""
    return data.replace({pd.NaT: None})
```

with this decorator:

```py
def skip_if_empty(default: Any | None):
    def decorate(decoratee):
        def decorator(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs):
            if len(decoratee_args) < 1:
                raise ValueError("The decorated function must have at least one argument.")

            if type(decoratee_args[0]) is not pd.DataFrame:
                raise ValueError("The first argument must be a DataFrame.")

            return default if decoratee_args[0].empty else decoratee(*decoratee_args, **decoratee_kwargs)

        decorator.__signature__ = inspect.signature(decoratee)
        return decorator

    return decorate
```

Now when I use several such methods that modify a `DataFrame` in a *chain* I don't have to worry about anything being `empty`:

```py
data = normalize_null(data)
data = do_something_else(data)
data = ...
```

---

Would you say it's ok to use decorators this way or mabe there is something else about it that could be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `functools.wraps`

The triple-nested function confused me for a minute, looking at it as a stranger, particularly as the decorator is not documented. You may want to look into [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which is a convenience function which does what you want with preserving signature, docs, name, etc. while being a standardised method.

### Names

To me, `default` doesn't immediately tell me what it's doing, `default_return` would be more obvious to me. Also, `skip_if_empty` implies that this function would work for any type, but is explicitly limited by:

```
if type(decoratee_args[0]) is not pd.DataFrame
```

to `pd.DataFrame`s. Perhaps `skip_if_empty_df` might be more clear. Either that, or you could make this more generically useful by allowing a second argument of permitted type:

```
def skip_if_empty(default: Any | None, allowed_types: tuple = (pd.DataFrame,)):
   ...
   if type(decoratee_args[0]) is not in allowed_types
```

### Pythonic

```
if len(decoratee_args) < 1
```

unless `len(tuple)` is liable to return a negative number what you're actually asking is:

```
if len(decoratee_args) == 0
```

or more pythonically

```
if not decoratee_args
```

Likewise

```
if type(decoratee_args[0]) is not pd.DataFrame
```

might want to be:

```
if not isinstance(decoratee_args[0], pd.DataFrame)
```

which would allow subclasses of `pd.DataFrame`s to work as well.

### Error messages

As a user, I would (and should) be unaware that any of the functions are in any way decorated, so seeing:

```
raise ValueError("The decorated function must have at least one argument.")
```

Is unhelpful. You might instead want:

```
raise ValueError(f"{decoratee.__name__} must have at least one argument.")
```

Comment: I like that and I have a question about this `allowed_types: tuple = (pd.DataFrame,)`. Would this also work with a list or are tuples preferable in cases like this? I guess probably because they are immutable, right?

Comment: It would work with a `list` and type annotations are just hints (by default), I would argue a `tuple` makes most sense here due to immutability and the fact that you will be defining it as a programmer rather than a user, but it could be any collection that supports `in` semantics. [`isinstance` also recommends `tuple`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)